# Sum each column for a table with over 20 columns without writing out each sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

so i need to get the sum of 20+ columns in a table that i'm working with and i'd really like to not have to write out the sum of every single column but i'm not sure that is possible. is there a way to get this to be dynamically written for all the columns in the table?

```
select isnull(osname, 'Total'), COUNT(*), SUM(col1), SUM(col2), SUM(col3)...sum(col27)
from usage
group by osname
with rollup
```

Comment: Now you know why normalization is a good thing ;)

Comment: I'd probably do something dumb like enumerate 1-27 in Excel and write a function to build the comma delimited list of `SUM(col&A#&)`

Comment: Do these columns have any unique characteristics?

Comment: Well, you _can_ use dynamic SQL, but you'd spend a lot more time troubleshooting the statement generation (there's examples on this site showing how to do this).  Personally, I'd just type it out to avoid the hassle.  As @TimSchmelter mentions, depending on your data set you may want to further normalize.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, most of my tables are normalized, this one is supposed to be used as a report for clients and now they want a report with averages. So my options are to work off the normalized data and then pivot it back into this format, or to do it this way.

Comment: @PM77-1 - the columns are just showing data usage by application, so it's not unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, if you can automate something, please do.  Typing out 20, 100 columns definitely is tedious.

My solution below uses a Table Variable Function to the get the list of numbered columns.  This can be reused again.

Second, I create some dynamic T-SQL using this function and applying your logic.  The WITH ROLLUP syntax is non-ISO compliant.  It was replaced in 2008 R2.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Lets get down to business.  I like creating a quick test table to my sure my syntax is correct.  Even I make mistakes.

```
--
-- Setup test data
--

-- Just playing around
use tempdb;
go

-- Drop test table
if object_id ('usage') > 0 
drop table usage
go

-- Create test table
create table usage
( osname varchar(16),
  col1 int,
  col2 int,
  col3 int,
  col4 int,
  col5 int
);
go

-- Test data
insert into usage values
('UNIX', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
('UNIX', 2, 4, 6, 8, 10),
('WIN7', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
('WIN7', 2, 4, 6, 8, 10),
('WIN8', 5, 10, 15, 20, 25);
go

-- Show the data
select * from usage;
go
```

Next, lets create a in-line table value function.  They are relatively quick.

http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/archive/2012/02/comparing-inline-and-multistatement-table-valued-functions/

```
--
-- Create helper function
--

-- Remove ITVF
if object_id('get_columns') > 0
drop function get_columns
go

-- Create ITVF
create function get_columns (@table_name sysname)
returns table
as
return 
(
  select top 100 column_id, name from sys.columns where object_id in
  (  select object_id from sys.tables t where t.name = @table_name )
  order by column_id
)
go

-- Get the columns
select * from get_columns('usage');
go
```

Now, lets put it all together to solve your problem.  Notice, you need to have column names which you left out.  I also changed over to ISO compliant syntax.

```
--
-- Solve the problem
--

-- Dynamic SQL
declare @var_tsql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT ';
select 
  @var_tsql += 
    case 
      when column_id <> 1 then 'SUM(' + name + ') as s_' + name + ', ' 
      else 'ISNULL(' + name + ', ''Total'') as s_name, '
    end 
from get_columns('usage');
select @var_tsql += 'COUNT(*) as s_count FROM usage GROUP BY ROLLUP(osname); '

--print @var_tsql
EXEC sp_executesql @var_tsql;
```

The print statement is used to debug any syntax errors.  Cut and paste into another window to check syntax.  The more you learn, the easier dynamic SQL will be.

The above dynamic TSQL works fine.  Here is your output.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would run:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'usage'
```

Then I would copy the columns into excel or google spreadsheet.

Then make column B in excel:

```
="SUM(" & A1 & "),"
```

And then copy that to all appropriate B cells.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get around it.

Type them out (shouldn't take more a minute).

Comment: Original TSQL is missing column headings.  Kinda a issue in a relational database.